# Searching for a textbook on Imaging

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, data-analysis, imaging, camera

I'm hoping someone can recommend a book that will cover the physics involved in optical range image capture. I have a degree in physics, so I am looking for something on the technical end.  To expand, I would like the book to cover the chemistry of how images are recorded on film and how we translate that data.  From there, I would like the book to move into an in-depth treatment of CMOS and CCD sensor's and the data processing required to make images.  Particularly, I'm hoping to gain a better understanding of the limits of digital sensors, but I am also looking to expand my knowledge in all areas of this topic.  Can anyone make a recommendation?

Comment: This may be outside the scope of this site, but I'm adding the recommendation banner and tag in case the community decides it's on topic.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good recommendation for a book that covers the physics involved in imaging is (regarding my Astrophysics background) 'Observational Astrophysics' by Pierre Lena, Daniel Rouan, Francois Lerund, Francois Mignard and Didier Pelat. Another recommendation, more basic, is 'Optics' by Eugen Hecht. Furhtermore, there are several Universities that have tons of lectures notes on imaging and such on their websites. For instance, here I share the website for the lecture notes on the course 'Image Science and Engineering', given by Dr. R. A. Schowengerdt, of the University of Arizona:

[https://uweb.engr.arizona.edu/~dial/ece425/ece425.html](https://uweb.engr.arizona.edu/%7Edial/ece425/ece425.html)

I don't know of any book that covers the chemistry behind the process of recording images on a film. However, I think any resource about the history of printing images would give at least a little of insight on that subject.

I hope this answer will help you, although almost 7 years have happened since you posted your question :(